# Laravel: Auth Directly redirecting to /home when i try to open /login or /register

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Auth scaffolding in laravel 5.5. But when i try to go to /login or /register,i am redirected to /home.
This is in my Login Controller:

public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

```
    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    // Check Whether username or email used
    $user = $request->input('user');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    if (filter_var($user, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        //email used
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $user, 'password' => $password, 'ustatus' => 'active'])){
        // Check and go to home
            $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
            return redirect()->intended('user/home');
        }
        else{
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors('error','User is invalid');
        }

    } else {
        //username used
        if(Auth::attempt(['user_name' => $user, 'password' => $password, 'ustatus' => 'active'])){
        // Check and go to home{
            $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
            return redirect()->intended('user/home');
        } else {
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors('error', 'User is invalid');
        }
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

My user model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $primaryKey = "user_id"; 
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Routes:

```
Auth::routes();
```

Can someone help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have and use a redirect if authenticated in the middleware

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and add it to your `Kernal.php` under the HTTP folder

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'auth'          => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'guest'         => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        ...
    ];
```

Comment: Everything is there as you said. It gives the same error

Comment: after that try it in private browsing where there are no saved cookies

Comment: It works for the first time, but go to directly where RedirectIfAuthenticated takes if i try to reopen /register or /login

Comment: It directly goes to /home (that  RedirectIfAuthenticated is taking to) instead of opening register or login

Comment: before trying the code I mentioned in the answer, check if it's a cache or cookies issue first, it seems that's the reason, and tell me what you get

Comment: try this redirect()->intended('register')->withErrors('error','User is invalid');

Comment: it's as if, it registers for the first time and then when i try to open register or login takes me to home thinking i am logged in user

Comment: it still goes to home

Comment: I get it now, you want it only to show if it's first-time register/login? after register, post a boolean variable lets call it 'first_time', and check if it is true in your code to redirect to 'user/home'

Comment: i don't want to show that, that what laravel is giving me and i don't want that

Comment: what's the expected result that you want

Comment: i want to see register when i open /register and same with login. How can a user go to home without register or login

Comment: public function __construct()
 {
  $this->middleware(['auth', 'guest']);
 }

Comment: and in the index() do Gate::authorize('your_authenticated_user');

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83922/discussion-between-yousef-and-ashfixed

Comment: i can't come over chat, my reputation is lower than 20